# How to solve exception: No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: java, libgdx

I am facing with this exception when I using `libgdx` in Java:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGenTextures(GL11.java:1403)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glGenTexture(LwjglGL20.java:348)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:120)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
    at Utils.Player$2.run(Player.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can i solve this? I'm using libgdx.
line 79 of Player.java:

```
TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture("textures/Textures.png"), 50, 15, 4, 4);
```

Comment: You are probably calling an OpenGL action before initializing the OpenGL context. But it's hard to tell without seeing your actual code (in other words: please provide it)

Answer (score 6):

You should not use Thread in libgdx actually, it is not recommended to use Thread. Html does not support threading and it will not work at Html. If you must use threading use,

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // process the result, e.g. add it to an Array<Result> field of the ApplicationListener.
            results.add(result);
         }
      });
```

To understand what is going on here, check it official document 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading

Comment: My program is only for windows pc. Should i use your code anyway?
And if i must, can you tell me what is this(// process the result, e.g. add it to an Array<Result> field of the ApplicationListener.
            results.add(result);)? because i haven't undestand

Comment: You can read the document below to clarify threading in libgdx. I would not use Thread if I were you, why do you need another thread to join into game loop. Gdx.app.postRunnable allows you to join game loop

Comment: You cannot access any OpenGL calls from spawned threads. This includes doing anything with a Texture or SpriteBatch. Doesn't matter what platform you are on. If you want to load Textures asynchronously, use AssetManager, which is set up to load the image on a background thread and then upload it to OpenGL on the GL thread.

Answer (score -2):

In Kotlin:

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable {

    // Your code in the context of OpenGL

}
```